# Python Pickle Streaming

Tags: python, pickle

I'd like to figure out how to compose this code in a streamable way:

```
data = pickle.dumps(obj)
fp = io.BytesIO(data)
```

Normally one can call pickle.dump, but this requires you to provide the writer file as an argument. Instead, I have an "upload_from_file" function, so I want to pass the file pointer to that function, hence the BytesIO code.

The problem with this way, is that I duplicated the data in memory, and I'd prefer if it were streamable.

Comment: This will be somewhat tricky since `pickle.dump()` (and the underlying lower-level function calls) are synchronous; you'd need a custom "fifo" style file-like object, run the dumping in a thread that feeds into that fifo and upload in the main thread from that fifo.

Comment: If the problem is just "too much data in memory", using a `tempfile.TemporaryFile` might help a bit. `pickle.dump(obj, temp)`, then `temp.seek(0)` (which returns the file pointer to the beginning of the file), then pass `temp` to `upload_from_file`.

Comment: (But that means the data will be written to disk, and if you're unlucky, into a `/tmp` tmpfs which is backed by memory...)

Comment: @AKX: Yep. Not much of a choice though; if they want to use something that expects a file-like object, they need a file-like object. The data needs to be somewhere, either in memory or on disk. Your solution can avoid either (sort of, by producing the data live at the same time it's being consumed), but it's going to be a lot more complicated. Note that using `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` with an explicit `dir` to use should avoid the risk of using temporary storage backed by memory (at the expense of reducing the OS's ability to avoid writes to disk when writes to disk aren't needed).

Comment: You could avoid two copies of the duplicated data in memory by just doing `fp = io.BytesIO()`, `pickle.dump(obj, fp)`, `fp.seek(0)` then passing `fp` to whatever wants it.

Comment: ShadowRanger, that does not avoid having two copies of the data. You have fp and you have obj, both in memory.

Answer (score 1):

## Approach 1: a thread and a Python FIFO

As I mentioned in the comments, you'd need a thread and a FIFO, and it gets hairy. (You may need to implement additional methods in the FIFO depending on what the actual `upload_from_file` function you have needs).

```
import os
import queue
import pickle
import threading
from typing import Union


class FIFOStream:
    def __init__(self, maxsize=0):
        self.queue = queue.Queue(maxsize)

    def write(self, chunk: Union[bytes, None]):
        if chunk:
            print(f"Queued {len(chunk)} bytes")
        self.queue.put(chunk)

    def read(self):
        chunk = self.queue.get(True)
        if chunk is None:  # EOF marker encountered
            raise EOFError()
        return chunk


def do_pickling(fifo: FIFOStream, obj):
    pickle.dump(obj, fifo, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    fifo.write(None)  # write EOF marker after Pickle is done


def upload_from_file(fifo):
    n = 0
    while True:
        try:
            chunk = fifo.read()
        except EOFError:
            break
        n += len(chunk)
        print(f"Uploading chunk of size {len(chunk)}")
    print(f"Finished uploading {n} bytes!")


def main():
    data = {a: os.urandom(1024) for a in range(500)}
    fifo = FIFOStream(maxsize=3)  # adjust maxsize to something larger in real use :)
    dumper = threading.Thread(target=do_pickling, args=(fifo, data))
    dumper.start()
    upload_from_file(fifo)
    dumper.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This prints out something like

```
Queued 66062 bytes
Queued 66057 bytes
Uploading chunk of size 66062
Queued 66057 bytes
Uploading chunk of size 66057
Queued 66057 bytes
Queued 66121 bytes
Queued 66121 bytes
Uploading chunk of size 66057
Queued 66121 bytes
Uploading chunk of size 66057
Uploading chunk of size 66121
Uploading chunk of size 66121
Queued 53727 bytes
Uploading chunk of size 66121
Uploading chunk of size 53727
Finished uploading 516323 bytes!
```

## Approach 2: a thread and a system FIFO

As [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) pointed out in the comments, you can also do this with `os.pipe()`, which gives you a FIFOesque file managed by the system:

```
import os
import pickle
import threading
from typing import IO


def upload_from_file(io: IO[bytes]):
    n = 0
    while True:
        try:
            chunk = io.read(65536)
        except EOFError:
            break
        if not chunk:  # Empty chunk = EOF
            break
        n += len(chunk)
        print(f"Uploading chunk of size {len(chunk)}")
    print(f"Finished uploading {n} bytes!")


def dump_and_close(data, file: IO[bytes]):
    pickle.dump(data, file, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    file.close()  # so the reader end will be EOF


def main():
    data = {a: os.urandom(1024) for a in range(500)}
    r_fd, w_fd = os.pipe()
    with open(r_fd, "rb") as r_file, open(w_fd, "wb") as w_file:
        dumper = threading.Thread(target=dump_and_close, args=(data, w_file))
        dumper.start()
        upload_from_file(r_file)
        dumper.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output is somewhat more boring though. ;-)

```
Uploading chunk of size 65536
Uploading chunk of size 65536
Uploading chunk of size 65536
Uploading chunk of size 65536
Uploading chunk of size 65536
Uploading chunk of size 65536
Uploading chunk of size 65536
Uploading chunk of size 57571
Finished uploading 516323 bytes!
```

Comment: If the goal is to minimize memory use, I'd *strongly* recommend setting a `maxsize` on the `queue.Queue`; otherwise, it's fairly likely most of the data will be pickled and waiting in memory before any network-based uploading code has processed more than a tiny number of blocks.

Comment: That said, is there a reason to use Python level queues here? Seems like `os.pipe` + `os.fdopen` could be used to solve this problem such that the reader is a true file object (e.g. it will work with many things that manipulate the underlying file descriptor directly, as long as they'd don't require a seekable file), and the nature of pipes means you'd block (avoiding unbounded memory consumption) "for free". It's entirely likely `upload_from_file` might do something like that (and it's highly likely to dislike an API that doesn't accept a `size` argument for `read`).

Comment: Maxsize added, great point. As for using `os.pipe`... yeah, that would also work, but I'd be wary about overflowing the pipe buffer.

Comment: Overflowing the pipe buffer isn't an issue, because you threaded the work, removing the risk of deadlock. The writer will block when the buffer fills (and the blocking will be capped by number of bytes, not number of writes, as with a `Queue`), the reader will block if it empties the buffer and still needs more data. In most cases, you'll be running with some degree of parallelism (writer runs ahead of the reader; when the reader empties the buffer, writer is already there to refill it). `os.fdopen` will (by default) add extra user-mode buffers on both sides too, so reader should rarely block.

Comment: Well, implementing this with `os.pipe()` wasn't hard either – edited that in too. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Nice. You're welcome! I'll note the output would be much less boring if the `upload_from_file` explicitly did something like `chunk = io.read1()` (possibly specifying a custom size) or the like, to simulate more reasonable upload code that's performing a single system call to get available data (without blocking for the *whole* file to be read) and writing it to the network before asking for another chunk.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Another good point. Edited that in.